# PureComponent not rendering

Tags: reactjs

hi I am trying to see the working a pure Component.

When I use the following code :

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Displayer from './Components/displayer';
const days=[
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday',
  'Sunday'
];

class App extends React.PureComponent{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={day:[]};
    this.increment=this.increment.bind(this);
    this.decrement=this.decrement.bind(this);
  }
  increment(){
    var demo=this.state.day;
    if(this.state.day.length<7)
      demo.push(days[this.state.day.length]);
    this.setState({day:demo});
  }
  decrement(){
    var demo=this.state.day;
    demo.pop();
    this.setState({day:demo});
  }
  render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <Displayer day={this.state.day} increment={this.increment} decrement={this.decrement}/>
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Displayer.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Displayer extends React.PureComponent{
    render(){
    var {day,increment,decrement}=this.props;
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={increment}>Add Day</button>
            <button onClick={decrement}>Remove Day</button>
            {
                day.map((item,index)=>{
                    return <h1 key={index}>{item}</h1>
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
    }
}

export default Displayer;
```

It is not giving me the desired result.

But when I use only React.Component it gives me the desired result.

[image]

Can someone help me to get this with the help of React.PureComponent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `this.state.day` as `array` in props.

> When comparing previous props and state to next, a shallow comparison
>   will check that primitives have the same value (eg, 1 equals 1 or that
>   true equals true).

**PureComponent will never perform the deep comparison. So that's why it's not working in your case.**

If you update your code slightly as below then it will work.

```
<Displayer 
   dayCount={this.state.day.length} // add it to make it work.
   day={this.state.day} increment={this.increment} decrement={this.decrement}/>
```

Also, You have to remove the `React.PureComponent` from `App` class and set it to `Component` only. After that it will work for you.

You can find the more information about the `PureComponent` at here.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent